# Python Divide by Zero resolves to NaN as part of Environment

Tags: python, environment, divide-by-zero

Bit of a strange question, but I'm migrating someone else's code and noticing something strange. When I run the code locally in Python 3.9, I get division by zero errors, but when the code is ran on this person's machine it resolves all divide by zero errors to NaN automatically.

We are running the exact same code so I have to assume this has something to do with the Python environment, but not sure how he accomplished this on the environment level.

```
0.0/0.0
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

His machine is running Python 3.6. It *feels* like he manually adjusted his environment somehow for this exact divide by zero issue.

Edit: So it looks like this is being caused by different Pandas versions. He is on 0.21.1, I'm on 1.4.1. Because of this, my dataframe columns get automatically typed as "objects" while his are typed as "floats", and division by zero works for floats...

Comment: The other machine is using Python 3.6, mine is using Python 3.9.

Comment: Are you using numpy or a library that uses numpy (for example pandas)?

Comment: Please make a [mre]. The error from the code you posted is different: `ZeroDivisionError: division by zero`. You'd only get `float division by zero` if you did something like `0.0 / 0` or `0 / 0.0`.

Comment: @Fran Yes, both machines have pandas installed and the script uses pandas.

Comment: That's your answer, then. Numpy/Pandas types are not the same as Python bulitin types

Comment: @OneCricketeer just a day or two ago I was arguing that Python floating point and numpy would deliver identical results, and someone pointed out that there were corner cases where they wouldn't. This appears to be one of those cases.

Comment: Regarding environment versioning, this is one use-case where using Docker, pipenv, and/or poetry really help